# Ruby Server #eliminate garbage build up

Tags: ruby, flash, networking

I have a working TCP/IP socket server that loads 3-flash files in succession. **How can I unload previous files and eliminate the garbage build up?**

2-Flash clients are active, 1-the loader, 2-the next Flash file being loaded, however "the Flash files don't unload." Maybe there's a "put - kill" method or something similar to addChild removeChild in as3. Any resource would help, since I'm not very familiar with Ruby.

**Files involved**

1. POLICY SERVER "server lets Flash files play" 
   policyserver_little.rb
2. RUBY TCP/IP SOCKET SERVER "server plays loader, that loads 3-Flash files"
   server_little#.rb
3. FLASH LOADER "client"
   loader_little.swf
4. FLASH MOVIES "numbers_odom.swf, numbers_fruits.swf, $mil.swf"
   "msg1, msg2, msg3"

**WHAT I SEE**
def worker==>end
There's no method to unload.

**RUBY SERVER** server_little#.rb

```
require 'socket'
require 'rexml/document'
include Socket::Constants

def create_xml_msg(msg, parent)
    el = nil
    msg.each do |key, value|
     if parent
   el = parent.add_element(key)
  else
   el = REXML::Element.new(key)
  end
  if value.instance_of?(Hash)
   create_xml_msg(value, el)
  else
   el.text = value.to_s
  end
 end
 return el
end

def worker(client, client_sockaddr, worker_number)
 $tid << Thread.new([client, client_sockaddr, worker_number]) do |cl|
  Thread.current[:number] = cl[2]
        puts("\nThread #{cl[2]} servicing #{Socket.unpack_sockaddr_in(cl[1]).join(':')}")
 #2
  seq_no = cl[2] * 10000000
  loop do
   begin

    msg1 = {"msg" => {"head" => {"type"  => "frctl", "seq_no" => seq_no, "version" => 1.0},
         "body" => {"file" => "numbers_odom.swf", "start" => 5, 
           "end" => 3000, "rate" => 40, "duration" => 60}}}
    msg2 = {"msg" => {"head" => {"type"  => "frctl", "seq_no" => seq_no, "version" => 1.0},
         "body" => {"file" => "numbers_fruits.swf", "start" => 5, "end" => 3000, "rate" => 40, "duration" => 60}}}
    msg3 = {"msg" => {"head" => {"type"  => "frctl", "seq_no" => seq_no, "version" => 1.0},
         "body" => {"file" => "$mil.swf", "start" => 5, 
           "end" => 3000, "rate" => 40, "duration" => 60}}}     

    [ msg1, msg2, msg3 ].each do |m|
     seq_no += 1
     m["msg"]["head"]["seq_no"] = seq_no
     xml_msg = create_xml_msg(m, nil)
     xml_msg.write(cl[0], 0)
     cl[0].putc 0
     sleep 10
    end
   rescue
    cl[0].close
    puts "\nThread #{Thread.current[:number]} exiting..."
    Thread.exit
   end
  end
 end
end

$tid = []  # array of active worker thread ids
$wno = []  # array of active worker numbers
$worker_count = 0
$max_workers = 3
$wlist = Array(1..$max_workers) #array of all possible worker numbers

socket = Socket.new( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 )
sockaddr = Socket.pack_sockaddr_in( 1999, '0.0.0.0' )
begin
 socket.bind( sockaddr )
 socket.listen( 5 )
rescue
 print $!.class, " ", $!
 sleep 3
 retry
end 

loop do
 begin
  $tid.each do |t|
   if (t.status == false || t.status == "aborting" )
    t.join
    $wno.delete(t[:number])
    $tid.delete(t)
    $worker_count -= 1
    puts("\nWorker count #{$worker_count}")
   end
  end
  client, client_sockaddr = socket.accept_nonblock
  if (client)
   if ($worker_count >= $max_workers)
    puts "\n too many clients...\n"
    client.puts("<msg>error: too many clients; closing connection...</msg>")
    client.close
   else
    $worker_count += 1
    $wlist.each do |w| #find a hole in worker number list
     if (!$wno.include?(w))
      $wno << w  #add new worker number to the active worker num array
      worker(client, client_sockaddr, w)
      break
     end
    end
    puts("\nWorker count #{$worker_count}")
   end
  end

 rescue Errno::EAGAIN, Errno::ECONNABORTED, Errno::EINTR, Errno::EWOULDBLOCK
  IO.select([socket], nil, nil, 1)
  retry
 end
end
```

**REFERENCE**
Ruby version 186-25
http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_threads.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very good resource for socket programming in ruby:
[Ruby Sockets: IBM](https://www6.software.ibm.com/developerworks/education/l-rubysocks/l-rubysocks-a4.pdf)

It was tough for me to get a feel for your code by reading through it, so I can't give you a direct answer. However I can tell you that if you want a good resource for sockets in ruby that pdf is it.

Answer (score 0):

In general i think the only way to eliminate garbage is to fork off a process, let it do the garbage-y stuff then die. If that's your question. NB that jruby, macruby, and rubinius have more advanced GC's.
-r